# How to assign a value to a variable from a text file?

Tags: php, variables, text-files, filenames

I am using a script to back up files from ftp. code is below.

```
include "recurseZip.php";
//Source file or directory to be compressed.
$src='source/images/black.png';
//Destination folder where we create Zip file.
$dst='backup';
$z=new recurseZip();
echo $z->compress($src,$dst);
```

Now I want to get values to **$src** from **source/files.txt** which contains a list of file names.

My .txt file:

```
index.php.bk-2013-12-02
index.php.bk-2013-12-07
index.php.bk-2013-12-10
index.php.bk-2013-12-20
index.php.bk-2013-12-26
function.php.bk-2013-12-20
function.php.bk-2013-12-23
contact.php.bk-2013-12-23
contact.php.bk-2013-12-30
```

**my source/files.txt** contains 10 file names those need to be assigned as values to the variable $src I am using this script http://ramui.com/articles/php-zip-files-and-directory.html

how can I do that.?

any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "get file name to $src from source/files.txt"

Comment: Do you want to get the file name i.e. black.png only and assign it to $src variable?

Comment: Do you want to read a file named files.txt and based on its content give name to $src??

Comment: Hey Starr, I have given my answer below. Check it out.

Comment: hi all.. thanks for that fast replies. I think my question is not clear enough. my **source/files.txt** contains 10 file names those need to be assigned as values to the variable **$src** I am using this script [link](http://ramui.com/articles/php-zip-files-and-directory.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, you want to get the file name from each line of the .txt file.

```
<?php
    $myFile = "files.txt";
    $lines = file($myFile);
    foreach($lines as $line){
    $file = basename($line);
    echo $file; 
    }
?>
```

**Answer to your old question variant**

You can use the [basename()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function. The manual says, "given a string containing the path to a file or directory, this function will return the trailing name component".

Now, you said "I want to get file name to $src from source/files.txt", so assuming from this, you are looking to get the file name i.e. **black.png**. This could be achieved using the basename() function as mentioned before.

```
<?php
$src='source/images/black.png';
$file = basename($src);
echo $file;
?>
```

**Output**

> black.png

http://ideone.com/p2b4sr

Comment: thanks for that. I need bit different that variable **$src** must get the values from the **source/files.txt** which contains a list of file names.

Comment: You clearly mentioned "Now I want to get file name to $src from source/files.txt how can I do that.?". From that, we implied that you want to get the file name from your $src variable and here you have an answer.

Comment: yeah sorry for that.. from my office desk I typed that in hurry... that need to be replaced as "Now I want to get values to $src from source/files.txt how can I do that.?". any ideas?"

Comment: We need to see more code, and data, what does the .txt file contain, with examples, so please consider editing your question Starr.

Comment: I've improved the question format. Can you please have a look at that?

Comment: Check my edit again. Hope it works.

Comment: yeah.. thanks a lot.. its echoing the file names correctly. but how can I assign those file names as values to **$src**? when I try `<?$src='$file';>?` it says **file not found** it means those file name are not assigned to the **$src** as value

Comment: $src is a variable, and can only hold a single value. You probably need to create and array called and add the file names in there. Please open up a new question and then ask there.

Comment: thanks.. I've created the array. its working fine.