# How to replace certain string with set of string list?

Tags: php, windows, text, replace, scripting

I have a file like so

```
"Hi, my name is Bob and I love blue."
```

I have a .txt with some names like so:

```
Jane
Janet
Tim
etc.etc.
```

I want to make new lines replacing bob with the names so it is like:

```
"Hi, my name is Jane and I love blue."
"Hi, my name is Janet and I love blue."
"Hi, my name is Tim and I love blue."
etc. etc.
```

How would I go about doing this (on Windows?)

Comment: You really should show your effort at solving this yourself. As it current;y stands it is too broad, because we have no idea where you are stuck.

Comment: You are way better off using a database for this. What you're asking is way too broad and will demand a somewhat complex method of pulling in the names from your text file, by exploding each name based on the way the text file is (as a new line, comma-seperated etc.). Start by Googling "assign variables from text file replace php" and go from there. One answer found on Stack is http://stackoverflow.com/a/20833952/ where you can start fiddling around with. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve it using a small batch script. See below -

Code -

```
@echo off

set /p "var=" <input.txt
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%i in (names.txt) do (
 set name=%%i
 call set "output=%%var:bob=!name!%%
 echo.!output!
REM echo.!name!
)
```

Here is the output -

```
D:\Scripts>type input.txt
Hi, my name is Bob and I love blue.
D:\Scripts>
D:\Scripts>
D:\Scripts>
D:\Scripts>op.bat
Hi, my name is Jane and I love blue.
Hi, my name is Janet and I love blue.
Hi, my name is Tim and I love blue.
```

Cheers, G

Comment: Thanks, I am on mobile but I will try this out!